# Estimates of $\Omega_{\text{av}}(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

Ramanujan proved that the average number of distinct divisors of $x$ for $x$ on $[1,n],
 ~\omega_{\text{av}}(n),$ and the average number of divisors including repetitions, $\Omega_{\text{av}}(n),$ are asymptotically equivalent,

$$\omega_{\text{av}}(n) \sim \Omega_{\text{av}}(n)\sim \log\log n.\hspace{10mm}(1)$$

Landau proved that

$$ \pi_k(n) \sim   \frac{n}{\log n} \frac{(\log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}.  $$

It seems possible (not claiming it) that a sharper estimate of the average $\Omega_{\text{av}}(n)$ on a large interval $[1,n]$ would be

$$\Omega_2(n) = (1/n)  \sum_{k=1}^r \frac{n}{\log n}\frac{k ( \log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} .\hspace{10mm} (2)$$

for sufficiently large $r$,  and  it makes sense in any case that $\omega_{\text{av}}(n)\leq \Omega_{\text{av}}(n).$

> Can we prove that
>
> $$(1/n)  \sum_{k=1}^r \frac{n}{\log n}\frac{k ( \log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}-\log\log n \sim 1? $$

Numerically it seems to work. I removed my own attempt to prove this because it was apparently wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that
$(1/n)  \sum_{k=1}^r \frac{n}{\log n}\frac{k ( \log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}-\log\log n 
\sim 1
$
for large $r$.

If
$f(x)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k-1+1) x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k-1) x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1) x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(k-1) x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{ x^{k}}{(k)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{ x^{k-1}}{(k-2)!}+e^x\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{ x^{k+1}}{(k)!}+e^x\\
&=xe^x+e^x\\
&=e^x(x+1)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$f(\ln \ln x)
=e^{\ln \ln x}(\ln \ln x+1)
=\ln x(\ln \ln x+1)
$
so that
$\frac1{\ln x}f(\ln \ln x)
=e^{\ln \ln x}(\ln \ln x+1)
=\ln \ln x+1
$.